# Angular v13 .eslintrc.json configuration for eslint-plugin-rxjs-angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, eslint, eslintrc, angular13

I want to use eslint-plugin-rxjs-angular in my Angular v13 project.
On their [github page](https://github.com/cartant/eslint-plugin-rxjs-angular) it says.

> Configure the parser and the parserOptions for ESLint. Here, I use a .eslintrc.js file for the configuration:

And then, there is a snippet.

```js
const { join } = require("path");
module.exports = {
  parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2019,
    project: join(__dirname, "./tsconfig.json"),
    sourceType: "module"
  },
  plugins: ["rxjs-angular"],
  extends: [],
  rules: {
    "rxjs-angular/prefer-async-pipe": "error"
  }
};
```

How do I implement the **.eslintrc.js** configuration above, in my **.eslintrc.json** file, which I've added below?

```json
{
  "root": true,
  "ignorePatterns": [
    "projects/**/*"
  ],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": [
        "*.ts"
      ],
      "parserOptions": {
        "project": [
          "tsconfig.json",
          "e2e/tsconfig.json"
        ],
        "createDefaultProgram": true
      },
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "@angular-eslint/component-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "prefix": "app",
            "style": "kebab-case",
            "type": "element"
          }
        ],
        "@angular-eslint/directive-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "prefix": "app",
            "style": "camelCase",
            "type": "attribute"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "files": [
        "*.html"
      ],
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/recommended"
      ],
      "rules": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, this is the way to do it.
The premade configs I extend, by @angular-eslint, takes care of the parser options behind the scenes.
Therefore, the only thing I had to do was:

In the `"files": ["*.ts"]` override, I added

```
"plugins": ["rxjs-angular"],
```

and

```
"rxjs-angular/prefer-async-pipe": "error"
```

in the rules section.

Comment: Not sure why that package has only 3 rules but it looks like the following one can be imported the same way as @jna describes 
https://github.com/cartant/eslint-plugin-rxjs
Just replace `"rxjs-angular"` with `"rxjs"` and you have most of the rules of the original package